# Connect to LDAP over SSL

Tags: ldap

I'm working on a project and connect to LDAP Server to verify user.
When setting LDAP Server I have a problem:

I used ldp.exe to test connection:

**- I can connect to LDAP over SSL (port 636) when I run ldp.exe on server (on windows server, ldp.exe and LDAP Server are in the same computer).**

**- But when run ldp.exe on Windows 7, I only connect to LDAP server by port 389 but over SSL (port 636) is failed (return 0x51)**

What's wrong on my server? Help me please!
And thanks so much...

Answer (score 1):

the first idea would be: check network configuration. You may start with "Windows 7 machine". Please, check if firewall isn't blocking 636. Another firewall may be between "Windows 7 machine" and server, which allows 389 and blocks 636. You can try to user tools as "telnet" or "tracert" to check it.

The second thing to check would be certificates at server side. If you want to enable SSL certificates, you have to use certificates and certificate authorities. My question would be: what's your current configuration?

In the official documentation from Microsoft is 0x51 treated as: LDAP_SERVER_DOWN 0x51 Cannot contact the LDAP server. So this is not very helpful, but "standard situation" with LDAP servers :-).